# Kendo grid :How to apply class for grid-column with JSP wrapper

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Looking for a way to apply a "class" attribute to a Kendo grid "grid-column".
I could find examples for the JavaScript way :

```
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [ {
        field: "name",
        title: "Name",
        attributes: {
                  "class": "table-cell",
          style: "text-align: right; font-size: 14px"
        }
      } ],
    dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
    });
    </script>
```

Looking for the JSP wrapper equivalent.
The  Kendo documentation at :

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/jsp/grid/column

has :

```
    <kendo:grid-column attributes="attributes">
    </kendo:grid-column>
```

Could not figure out a way to get this to work.

The desired output must be like :

```
    <td class="table-cell"
```

Comment: try this: `<kendo:grid-column attributes="{'class':'table-cell'}"></kendo:grid-column>`

Comment: Tried. Did not work.<td{'class':'table-cell'} role="gridcell">xyz</td{'class':'table-cell'}>

Comment: attributes=" class=table-cell" seems to be working. Working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <kendo:grid-column attributes=" class=table-cell"></kendo:grid-column>
```

worked. Notice the white space after the start double quote. This worked with Kendo version 2013.3.1119